# How to change custom component height programatically

Tags: android

I've prepared custom component based on LinearLayout. Whole component is defined in XML. Currently to use it you have to write:

```
<com.xxx.android.components.TopMenu 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
/>
```

Is it possible to set width and height in the java constructor? So it would be possible to write just:

```
<com.xxx.android.components.TopMenu />
```

I've tried to modify and set LayoutParams, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the constructor, but in the `onFinishInflate()` callback to your custom widget, I this might work.